# Extract content from RSS feed into php file

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I am a newbie in this field and any help would be really appreciated. So here's the question- Suppose if I have a RSS feed of a particular site and I want to extract its content and store it in a PHP script, how would I do it? I want to define particular names like $title, $tag, $date etc and save the extracted content into my database and use it from there. Currently, I am using http://dapper.com for this purpose but it is too slow and inaccurate, so I want to do it manually. If you could suggest me a way of doing this or direct me to some links online, it would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An rss feed is an xml file.  Use simplexml:  http://us.php.net/simplexml.  Here's a blog post showing just how easy it is, and throws in a quick curl example to show how to fetch the actual feed data:  http://return-true.com/2010/04/parsing-a-rss-feed-with-php-using-simplexml/

Comment: Hi, you said use simplexml, is that something different from using html DOM parser? if yes, can you please let me know which is the easier one & which is the more efficient? thanks,

Comment: Yes simplexml is not the DOM parser.  It's a lightweight library that is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many PHP classes written specifically for RSS parsing.

You might want to try [magpierss](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi. I was searching for something similar before asking this question, and came across simplepie several times. Will that serve my purpose efficiently?

Comment: @Aditya: http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/why_would_i_use_simplepie_over_something_else